# PL/SQL Procedure .. trying to relate with SQL

Tags: sql, database, plsql

I am trying to write queries for the below table where

```
  field1    field2               field3   field4  field5 field6    field7
1   45     ABC_DEF_Sucess_cust1    RAJ       4       -2    8-10-2015     svsdsdv
2   46     ABC_DEF_Sucess_cust2    RAJ       8       -2    8-10-2015     hffhfh
3   47     ABC_DEF_failure_cust3   BIH       8       -2    8-10-2015     sfsfs
.
.
```

I need the avg value of `field4` when `Field3` is unique (suppose RAJ here) and `field2` starts with `ABC_DEF_uniquevalue (here Sucess) _cust*` that is (4 + 8) / 2 = 6

The table name is `Test`

I don't know PL/SQL, please help me out. I was trying to relate it with SQL like

```
select * from sqm_kpi_values where kpiid = 'ABC_DEF_%'
```

Comment: Why do you want to write a stored procedure for this?

Comment: No matter how I read the data, `field3` is a string.  What is the average value of a string?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I took the liberty to fix OP's typo: average should be of `field4` (or so I guess).

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the average of field 4 with respect to field 3 then You can try this:-

```
SELECT FIELD3, AVG(FIELD4)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY FIELD3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like the following will work:

```
SELECT FIELD3, AVG(FIELD4)
  FROM SOME_TABLE
  WHERE FIELD2 LIKE 'ABC_DEF_Sucess%'
  GROUP BY FIELD3;
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
select avg(field4), field3 from test where field2 like 'ABC_DEF_SUCCESS%' group by field3;
```

Use whatever string you need in the `LIKE` clause if what I have provided is not correct.